# Error pasting data org.json.JSONException

Tags: android, mysql, json

this is json code and httpurlconnection get data from json

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void...params){
        InputStream is=null;

        String result="";

        String urlDate="http://pangkortourism.ga/fyp/player.php";

        BufferedReader reader=null;

        try{

            URL urlp=new URL(urlDate);

            try {
                HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) urlp.openConnection();
                c.setRequestMethod("GET");
                c.setReadTimeout(10000);
                c.connect();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

                StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buf.append(line);
                }

                result = buf.toString();
            }
            finally {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {


            Log.e("MalformedURLException", "MalformedURLException " + e.toString());
        }



        //parse json data

        try{

            // Remove unexpected characters that might be added to beginning of the string

                    result=result.substring(result.indexOf("["));

            JSONArray jArray =new JSONArray(result);

            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){

                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                Product p=new Product();

                p.setid(json_data.getString("id"));

                p.setitem(json_data.getInt("item"));
                records.add(p);
            }

        }

        catch(Exception e){

            Log.e("ERROR", "Error pasting data "+e.toString());
        }
        return null;

    }
```

mysql database data

json code

```
[
    {"0":"1","id":"1","1":"pizza","item":"pizza"},
    {"0":"2","id":"2","1":"burger","item":"burger"}
]
```

Error in android studio

> 04-07 11:58:12.527 23232-23303/com.khor.newtry6 E/ERROR: Error pasting
>   data org.json.JSONException: Value pizza at item of type
>   java.lang.String cannot be converted to int 04-07 11:58:12.542
>   23232-23232/com.khor.newtry6 E/size: 0

Comment: json_data.getInt("item")); item is not numeric

Comment: question was answered by me first and rest copied paste :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove following line from your code because it sign to indicate json arrya

result=result.substring(result.indexOf("["));

and then after try it may be work.
And also change item  `p.setitem(json_data.getInt("item"));` with  `p.setitem(json_data.getString("item"));`

Answer (score 0):

"item" filed is String not integer hence

Change below :

```
p.setitem(json_data.getString("item"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using p.setitem(json_data.getString("item")); INSTEAD OF

p.setitem(json_data.getInt("item"));

and change argument datatype in method  p.setitem(); to String..

i.e. Signature for p.setitem(); method should be:

public void setitem(String item){

this.item =item;

}